# Why didn't I reclaim all this size from a Postgresql table DROP?

Tags: postgresql

I had a 103GB (pgAdmin III reported it as such in 'Statistics' of the table) table in Postgresql 8.4.  I dropped it.  Since then, its only recovered about 60GB worth of space back to the system ....

Where'd the rest of it go and what can I do to get it back?

Answer (score 2):

Probably need to do a vacuum? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-vacuum.html

Comment: And a quote from the manual entry "Therefore it's necessary to do VACUUM periodically, especially on frequently-updated tables."

Comment: I dropped the table ....how can I vacuum something that doesn't exist?

Comment: If I had just deleted I wouldn't get *any* space back until a vacuum *full* or cluster anyway.

Comment: oh yeah... woops